# Print how many times appears a specific digit in a number

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop

The return type is void and there is one input parameter and I am trying to use a while loop to print out how many of a certain number there is an the input integer.

So as an example int i = 32001; then I want too know how many 0's there are in the int and the output would be 2 cause there's only two 0's in that int.

My code below for some reason only outputs 0 and I don't know why. Could someone pls fix or help.

And please don't use any power tools or certain methods that do the work for you and you can use for loop or while loop.

```
public class loopPrr
{

public void howMany0(int i){
        
        
        int n = 0;
        int howmany = 0;
        char z = '0';
         while(i <= 0){
             ++i;
            if(i == z){
                howmany++;  
            }
        }
       
         System.out.println(howmany);
    }


public static void main(String args[]){
        
        loopPrr n = new loopPrr();
    
        
        n.howMany0(32001);
        
        
    
    
    }





}
```

Comment: a `char` 0 will never be equivalent to an `int` 0

Comment: If you want to check if the char `'0'` is in a number, you will want to convert your number to a string. Strings contain characters; ints do not.

Comment: @sleepToken that's not true, unless you meant a `char` `'0'`.

Comment: To begin with you need to take  step back, and think about basic school math and decimal arithmetic, and how that can be used to get a single digit from the number and how to get the remainder of the number without that digit.

Comment: Worth debugging to watch what is going on. Is 32001 ever <= 0? That may be a question to ask yourself. You may want to think about the data types you are working with. Maybe parse the integer into a String.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca yes, I mean the `char` '0', not that `char` with a value of 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the next code. The logic is very simple, perform a mod 10 to get the most-right digit, count it if is the target, divide by 10 to remove the last digit, and repeat.

```
public void countNumber(int n, final int target) {

    int count = 0;

    if (n == target) {
        count = 1;
    }
    else {
        while (n != 0) {
            if (n % 10 == target)
                count++;

            n /= 10;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(count);
}
```

Comment: I never thought about dividing it by 10 to get the next set of digits. Thank you for sharing your idea and method.

Comment: I've updated the answer adding a target parameter, this way you can use the method with other numbers and not only zero.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can split your number into a character array and see how many zeros you have:

```
public void howMany0(int i) {
    if (i == 0) return 1;
    String str = String.valueOf(i);
    char[] digits = str.toCharArray();
    int howmany = 0;
    char z = '0';
    for (char c : digits) {
        if (c == z) {
            howmany++;
        }
    }
    return howmany;
}
```

Comment: This solution requires extra allocation, because must convert to string, and then create an array out of it. Is not efficient.

Comment: @API_1024 Yes it does, but you can refactor the function and use it to find number of zeros (or any other digit) in a number that is large enough to be stored in an Integer (e.g. a few hundred digit number, stored as a string).
Also i provide an alternative solution, maybe the use case does not require my solution.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I understand now. I think I can use your method idea for some specific leetcode and hackerrank problems. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to get a frequency count of all the digits is as follows:

```
int[] freq = new int[10];
int numb = 2829921;
while (numb > 0) {
    // use the digit as the index and bump the count
    freq[numb % 10]++;
    numb /= 10;
}
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    // skip empty slots
    if (freq[i] > 0) {
        int k = freq[i];
        System.out
                .println(k + " " + i + ((k > 1) ? "'s" : ""));
    }
}
```

Prints

```
1 1
3 2's
1 8
2 9's
```

Comment: This solution is not so efficient as it requires memory allocation, plus 2 passes

Comment: You clearly missed the point.  It requires a single pass to get the the count.  But of course you have to print them.  But the point is it finds the count of all the digits.

Comment: Your answer would be fine if the question was to print the count of all the different digits, then your answer would be right, but the question is about 1 specific digit and not the count of each one of them.

Comment: I know that. I was offering a more general solution.  Did you see my first statement?